# in AngularJS, JWT Authorization header is undefined

Tags: angularjs, jwt

I am trying to access an api using jwt. When I post with credentials, I get the `id_token` from server. I extract it, but when I try to add the token to the next requests in `Authorization header` using `Bearer`, the token is shown as `undefined`, therefor receiving the 500 Internal Error as "JWT strings must contain exactly 2 period characters. Found: 0". The console error is shown in the picture

My code is as following:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
//$scope.tok = '';
$http({
    method : "POST",
    url : "http://server.com/api/authenticate",
    data: '{"username":"username","password":"password","rememberMe":true}',
    headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            }
    }).then(
    function mySuccess(response){
        $scope.token = response.data.id_token;
    }, function myError(response){
        console.log(response);
    });

$http({
    method: "GET",
    url: "http://server.com/api/account",
    data: '',
    headers:{"Authorization": "Bearer " + $scope.token,
             "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
}).then(
    function mySuccess(response){
        console.log(response);
    }, function myError(response){
        console.log(response);
    });

});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course that happens because your token is returning AFTER your second request.
On the fly you can solve it like this:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $http){
//$scope.tok = '';
$http({
    method : "POST",
    url : "http://server.com/api/authenticate",
    data: '{"username":"username","password":"password","rememberMe":true}',
    headers:{"Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
            }
    }).then(
    function mySuccess(response){
        $scope.token = response.data.id_token;
        $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "http://server.com/api/account",
            data: '',
            headers:{"Authorization": "Bearer " + $scope.token,
                 "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=UTF-8"}
        }).then(
            function mySuccess(response){
                console.log(response);
            }, function myError(response){
                console.log(response);
            });

        });
    }, function myError(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
```